# How to replace all values in data frame with another data frame except NA?

Tags: r, replace

I'd like to replace values in data frame A with data frame b

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
 s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
 b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
 df_A = data.frame(n, s, b) 


 n = c(2, 4, NA) 
 s = c("aa", NA, "bb") 
 b = c(TRUE, NA, TRUE) 
 df1_B = data.frame(n, s, b)
```

My expected result would look like:

```
n = c(2, 4, 5) 
 s = c("aa", "bb", "bb") 
 b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
 result = data.frame(n, s, b)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way -

```
df1_B[is.na(df1_B)] <- df_A[is.na(df1_B)]

  n  s     b
1 2 aa  TRUE
2 4 bb FALSE
3 5 bb  TRUE
```